# Why are information_schema and performance_schema not utf8mb4 (and should I care)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation, information-schema, utf8mb4

I have been going through my MariaDB installation with a fine-toothed comb trying to update everything from utf8 (3-byte flavor) to utf8mb4. It's correct in my.cnf, all my databases, and all applicable tables and columns thereof. And when I create new databases with no options, it does create them with the correct collation. But see this screenshot of Adminer - two of the three infrastructure databases are still utf8. **Is this okay? If not, how should I change them?** This server isn't live yet, but it's very close to ready, so I'd rather not do something stupid and break the DB engine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* change anything in `mysql`, `performance_schema`, or `information_schema`.

Beware of any indexed `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8` -- they will have trouble with a limit of 767 bytes on the index.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Yeah, I'm checking on my indexes, but I think I'm okay.